# How to publish update to visual studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am trying to publish an update to my visual studio extension. I have followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-update-a-visual-studio-extension , however, when I try to upload my updated VSIX file (by pressing 'New Extension' and selecting the VSIX file), I get the following error:

```
The VSIX ID in the provided file is already in use. Every extension needs to have an unique ID. Provide a file with an unique ID.
```

How do I publish this update? I don't see an update button anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

There is **...** right to your extension name, clicking on it opens a menu with the **Edit** command:

[image]

Comment: My concern was that this was not enough, but the fact is it just takes some time to appear in Azure DevOps. I left the office and in less than an hour when I got home, I could see the updated task in my pipeline.